# Passing data from one html page to another with java servlets

Tags: java, html, servlets, post, web

So I have one html form in "File1.html"

```
<form action="MyServlet" method="post">
    MyData: <input type="text" name="data"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then in my servlet I do the following:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher myDispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("File2.html");
    myDispatch.forward(request, response);
    }
```

So after the user hits the "submit" button in File1, the servlet takes the user to File2. But how do I access the data that was inputed in the first file in the second file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before using the Dispatcher set the attribute you want to pass

```
request.setAttribute("AttributeName","This is the Attribute value.");
```

in your case

```
request.setAttribute("data",request.getParameter("data"));
```

and on the dispached page , get it by

```
String something =  request.getAttribute("data");
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question though, is it legal to just call String something = "..." in HTML? Or do I need to use Javascript? I ask because eventually I want to display the data inside a <p></p>

Comment: Then I don't understand where you wrote "and on the dispatched page, get it by...". The dispatched page is my html file. I plan on using the data inside the html file and displaying it to the screen.

Comment: the request dispatcher should call another servlet or jsp page , there you can call it , request object cant be passed to HTML page .you can treat your JSP page like your HTML page

Answer (score 0):

You can get it this way:-

`request.getParameter("param");`

Comment: Cool, so do I call this function from within the html file?. Or from the servlet? And if I call it from the servlet, I would still need to pass it into the html file somehow, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can put parameter to request:

```
String data = request.getParameter("data");
request.setAttribute("key",data);
myDispatch.forward(request, response);
```

and you can get data from new servlet or jsp like :

```
Object data = request.getAttribute("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect to a static html file, you can not get the parameter or attribute via servlet.

If you don't have any business in the servlet, you can just use , then get the data from File2.html via javascript.

---

Or you can redirect to the File2.html in your servlet and attach the data by query string like "File2.html?name=blablabla" and use javascript in File2.html to get these data.

btw, in javascript you can use window.location.href to get current url which include the query string.